# Variance of error term is nonconstant between observations

Tags: predictive-models, boosting, artificial-intelligence

[image]I used XGB algorithm to train a model. The task is to train models to predict human personality based on his/her personal photo. We found some significant features when we extracted them by Pearson correlation, but when it comes to the actual versus the predicted; the results are converged in a horizontal line. How to proceed?

The training data is 2k samples, consist of 60 different facial features (https://console.faceplusplus.com/documents/6329465) and scores for 5 personality traits.

Actual data is personal photos and the predicted data is the personality score.

Comment: What is actual and predicted? Describe your data and your dimensions.

Comment: @user2974951 The training data is 2k samples, consist of 60 different facial features (https://console.faceplusplus.com/documents/6329465) and scores for 5 personality traits. Actual data is personal photos and the predicted data is the personality score.

Comment: So the data points should follow the line? Which means that your model hasn't learned much since it mostly predicts in the same narrow range of values. Additional tuning is required. As for significant features they could very well be describing random noise.

Comment: @user2974951 what do you mean by additional tuning? change the algorithm? categorize features? what things could fits here? Thanks.

Comment: That you may have to play with the many different parameters of the XGB model, or you may have to use a different model altogether. This is not an easy problem and there are no easy solutions.